# Beat sb. to the punch

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of "beat somebody to the punch" . Could you please explain to me in a simple way. English is not my mother tongue. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

It means to do or say something before someone else also trying to do or say the same thing. Example.

> I better buy this car before someone beats me to the punch.

You could also just use "beat".

> I wanted to buy the car, but he beat me to it.

Your question might be put on hold, or get closed, since you could find the answer to this question from a simple google search. Try doing some basic research before asking questions on this site.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you think that the quastion is too easy to answer or is not deserving an answer than you should not have written a comment.

Comment: You are very new to this site, so instead of putting your question on hold, I thought I could give it an answer, and inform you that your question is too simple. Just remember till next time, do some research. If you can't find anything concise after a few searches, then you can ask your question here. @BaşakKüçük

Comment: I have just searched but the results on the internet haven't made me certain. So this is why i asked on this side

Comment: After one search, I found this. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/beat-someone-to-the-punch        It literally says: "To do something before someone else".   It couldn't be more clear. @BaşakKüçük

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your effort to defeating me. By.

Comment: I'm not trying to defeat you, just trying to give you some tips about how this site works. When I was new to the site, most of my questions were put on hold and then closed. I often felt it was unfair, but then I learned what this site is about. Sorry if I was rude to you.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about. With the last words that you've just said, I'm feeling better now. Thank you anyway I'll ask the next quastion as you said.

Comment: I prepared a rather extensive answer to this question, including an attestation predating etymonline's by several years, but with this as a duplicate of an already closed question, I have no place to post it.